# Can we do networking by java programs like Manage switches do?

Tags: java, c, sockets, networking

I am using Java program with few Embedded boards which has c program as firmware written in c by my friend.
Java program send & receive frames from those embedded boards by socket programming. Embedded boards also send & receive frames from Java program with help of its firmware.
Each board has connected to manage switch(i called as member switches). Each board has only 1 Ethernet port.
All member switches connected to one Main manage switch which has connected to PC where Java program runs.
Network topology is Daisy chain topology which support Redundancy in networking till 1 link failure.

Now i am thinking i can change in Java & my friend can change in firmware so we can remove all manage switches from whole network.
There can be 2 methods
1. No switch/bridge in whole network!
So if i connect 2 network cards in my pc so i get 2 Ethernet ports & try to take control it by my program, then all work done by Manage switches can be handle by Java program!
For that i think Each embedded board also need 2 Ethernet ports. So we can manage same topology but without any kind of manage switches.
something looks same as following image but without switch/bridge:-
[image]
But As Token ring/IEEE 802.5 (token ring is a pretty poor design) but my current manage switches use IEEE standards as follows:-

```
IEEE 802.3 for 10Base-T
IEEE 802.3u for 100Base-TX and 100Base-FX
IEEE 802.3z for 1000Base-X
IEEE 802.3ab for 1000Base-T
IEEE 802.3ad for LACP (Link Aggregation Control Protocol )
IEEE 802.3x for Flow control
IEEE 802.1D for STP (Spanning Tree Protocol)
IEEE 802.1p for COS (Class of Service)
IEEE 802.1Q for VLAN Tagging
IEEE 802.1w for RSTP (Rapid Spanning Tree Protocol)
IEEE 802.1s for MSTP (Multiple Spanning Tree Protocol)
IEEE 802.1x for Authentication
```

2. If 1 manage switch between pc & embedded boards.
   use 1 manageable switch which connected between pc which has java program & all embedded boards(connected with first board & last board in whole topology).

For functionality implementation which similar to manage switches has like Redundancy.
I try to figure out requirements related to this as follows:-
I have to at-least 5 programs like below:-
1. Message Identification :- When some board or java program send frame, then till reach to its destination it go via few boards or Java program so it should be handle like if i am board then 'this message not for me but for abc so i forward it to my neighbor & i will not repeat this so message flood not happens'.

2. Handling Port behavior :- Physical network port should work as we need example sending port, receiver port, or bi-directional port.
3. Maintaining Routing & other Tables:- In networking switches maintain Routing & other tables that's why we not have head-ache about how our data goes to sender to receiver. Something like this i need to implement in java program.
4. Finding Shortest path:- Like Dijkstra's algorithm or OSPF, RIP etc something should implement in program.
5. Message Transferring :- As message goes to sender to receiver there might be few nodes comes in the path, as manage switches cross verify those messages for whom, if not for it or related to its connected board then it transfers to someone who in the path. Similarly i have to implement in program.

As we have 2 people, 1 for java & 2nd for C. I have to take lead in this so all thinking should done by me!
I need help for my thoughts!

Now question for this forum is as follows:-
1. Is my thinking is in right direction?
2. By Java, can i manage all above theories? As till date i use simple socket programming where i not bother what happens after

```
socket.getoutputstream().write(byte[])
```

3. If yes then any expert guidance?
4. If no then Reasons?
5. Any other thing missing in this?

Please i need clue/help/guidance!

Comment: Existing socket implementations in Java are not that low level; you have to resort to native code here at some point

Comment: I got it. By JNI i can manage! But will it possible? Is this idea feasible? Same question i asked on other forum, those guys think this thing done by 10 years ago in IBM...etc bring me morally down.